# How to properly satisfy all linker dependencies in following pybind11 project?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, pybind11

I am porting a large library to pybind11 for python interface. However I have stuck where I seemingly am either getting `multiple declaration error` at linker stage, or during python import I get `symbol not found` error. The simplified project structure is as given below

CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

# set the project name
project(tmp VERSION 1.0)

find_package(EnvModules REQUIRED)
env_module(load python39)


find_package(PythonInterp REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(pybind11/include)

add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(TMP py_modules.cpp
                        SubConfiguration.cpp)
# pybind11_add_module(TMP py_modules.cpp)
```

Source files:
`py_modules.cpp`

```
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "calculateStress.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(TMP, m){
    py::class_<Stencil>(m, "Stencil")
            .def(py::init<double &>());
    py::class_<SubConfiguration>(m, "SubConfiguration")
            .def(py::init<Stencil &>());
}
```

2. `calculateStress.h`

```
#ifndef CALCULATESTRESS_H_
#define CALCULATESTRESS_H_

#include "SubConfiguration.h"

#endif /* CALCULATESTRESS_H_ */
```

3. `SubConfiguration.h`

```
#ifndef SRC_SUBCONFIGURATION_H_
#define SRC_SUBCONFIGURATION_H_

#include "Stencil.h"

class SubConfiguration
{
public:
    double& parent;
    SubConfiguration(Stencil& stencil);
};

#endif /* SRC_SUBCONFIGURATION_H_ */
```

4. `SubConfiguration.cpp`

```
#include "SubConfiguration.h"

SubConfiguration::SubConfiguration(Stencil& stencil) :
    parent(stencil.parent)
{}
```

5. `Stencil.h`

```
#ifndef SRC_STENCIL_H_
#define SRC_STENCIL_H_

class Stencil {
public:
    double parent;
    Stencil(double&);
};

Stencil::Stencil(double& parent) : parent(parent) { }

#endif /* SRC_STENCIL_H_ */
```

I think all import guards are properly set.

Now when I give `pybind11_add_module(TMP py_modules.cpp)` compile option, I get the TMP module but while importing I get error `undefined symbol: _ZN16SubConfigurationC1ER7Stencil`

Whereas with `pybind11_add_module(TMP py_modules.cpp SubConfiguration.cpp)` I get following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/TMP.dir/SubConfiguration.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): in function `Stencil::Stencil(double&)':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Stencil::Stencil(double&)'; CMakeFiles/TMP.dir/py_modules.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/TMP.dir/SubConfiguration.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): in function `Stencil::Stencil(double&)':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Stencil::Stencil(double&)'; CMakeFiles/TMP.dir/py_modules.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/TMP.dir/build.make:99: TMP.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:96: CMakeFiles/TMP.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

How do I properly set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Stencil.h gets included by both py_modules.cpp and SubConfiguration.cpp. The include guards will only protect against double includes from a single compilation unit (cpp file).

Remove the implementation of the Stencil constructor from `Stencil.h` and move it into a new file `Stencil.cpp` as

```cpp
#include "Stencil.h"
Stencil::Stencil(double& parent) : parent(parent) { }
```

Then add the new file to your module

```
...
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(TMP py_modules.cpp SubConfiguration.cpp Stencil.cpp )
```

UPDATE (to reflect comments)

If you have a templated class, you do not need necessarily to include the implementation in the header. You can use explicit template instantiation as in this example:

In the header `doit.h`

```cpp
template< typename T >
T addsome( T t );
```

In the body `doit.cpp`

```cpp
#include "doit.h"

// Add explicit template instantiations for the types you care
// #include <doit.h>
template<> 
int addsome<int>( int t ) {
    return t+1;
}
template<> 
double addsome<double>( double t ) {
    return t+2;
}
```

In main.cpp or where you use it

```cpp
int main() {
    int res = addsome<int>( 1 ); // This will link against the compiled body doit.cpp
}
```

Comment: Yes, or put `inline` before `Stencil::Stencil` if you want to define it in the header, to avoid multiple definitions.

Comment: What if the Stencil class also contain a templated function? I cannot seperate definition then can I?

Comment: @ipcamit  With templates the linkers are aware that duplication is expected.  But you technically can separate the implementation - I do this all the time.  I extended the response above.